# Is there a standard C++ function, that is analogue to Address-of operator &?

Tags: c++, stl, functor, memory-address

Is there a standard C++ function, that is analogue to Address-of operator &, that I can use as a function object with stl entities like std::transform and std::compose1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::addressof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) could suit your purpose. Note that the behaviour is slightly different to plain `operator&` if the type has an overload for that operator.

Comment: Do you know of a non C++11 way of doing that? I need C++03. There's a addressof in <boost/utility.hpp>.

Comment: @mezhaka you can roll out your own, depending on the desired functionality. The link in my answer has a possible implementation.

Comment: @juanchopanza: am I missing something, or is that implementation wrong on the basis that the C-style cast `(char&)` is a `static_cast` in the case where `T` overloads `operator char &`? http://ideone.com/7aGun5

Comment: @juanchopanza: nuts, and it's on a Wiki. Does that mean I should fix it?

Comment: @SteveJessop If you are sure about it, then yeah. I am not confident enough to do it myself without some further reading of the standard and some experimentation.

Comment: @juanchopanza: the standard is terse, it says "even in the presence of an overloaded `operator&`" but doesn't explicitly mention "even in the presence of overloaded conversion operators". So I'm pretty sure that the implementation there doesn't conform but I'm not absolutely sure. I'm also not confident of making a major correction on a Wiki I've never edited before and don't really have a feel for :-(

Comment: @SteveJessop I don't know if you had anything to do with it, but I see the example in cppreference.com has been fixed.

Comment: I fixed it, thanks to whoever brought it up on the talk page. Incidentally, the (char&) version was from LLVM libc++, we should tell @HowardHinnant.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you're looking for is [`std::addressof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof).

Comment: And since that's a function rather than an AdaptableUnaryFunction, you can wrap it with `std::function` or `std::ptr_fun` for use with `compose1`. Not that `compose1` is standard.

Comment: Do you know of a non C++11 way of doing that? I need C++03. There's a addressof in <boost/utility.hpp>.

Comment: @mezhaka: in C++03 you'll just have to write your own or use Boost. It's not complicated, the trick is just to avoid any `operator&` overload on `T` by casting to `char&`, taking the address, then casting back to `T*`. If you don't need the "real" address (i.e. you're happy to call overloaded `operator&`) then it's even simpler: `template <typename T> T* ampersand(T &t) { return &t; }`.

Comment: @mezhaka: oh yes, and if you do write your own you have to `reinterpret_cast` to `char&`. Don't `static_cast` or C-style cast, in case the class also overloads `operator char &`. And then there's some messing around to deal with const-qualified types (since `reinterpret_cast` can't remove cv-qualifiers from references). Even with that it's still a one-liner, just look at the Boost source .